# Iterative to recursion

Tags: java, recursion, topological-sort

I'm looking at topological sorting, and I came across this function that does the topologicalSort recursively.

```
void topologicalSortUtil(int v, Boolean visited[],Stack stack)
{
    // Mark the current node as visited.
    visited[v] = true;
    Integer i;

    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
    Iterator<Integer> it = adj[v].iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        i = it.next();
        if (!visited[i])
            topologicalSortUtil(i, visited, stack);
    }

    // Push current vertex to stack which stores result
    stack.push(new Integer(v));
}
```

How would I go about in doing this iteratively? What should my approach process be when it comes down to breaking down recursive functions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is adj definition ?

Comment: You seem to have got the portion of code from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/ and it is all well explained there.

Comment: Note that this is just traversing the graph depth first with post-order visits.  There are many references for iterative DFS on a graph.